# What's a more concise way to count the number of times an element occurs in a list in J?

Tags: j

Here's the (probably naive) way I've done it:

```
count =: 4 : '# (#~ =&x) y'"1 0 1
```

In other words, if I say `4 count 3 4 4 3 4 7 9` the result is `3`, because `4` occurs 3 three times in the given list.

This works perfectly, but I wonder whether J offers some more concise way to phrase this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I do this, knowing that I'm only ever going to have a list and not a matrix, I use:

```
count =: 4 : '+/x=y'
```

Or for multiple searches in the list:

```
count =: 4 : '+/x=y'"0 1
```

Your method copies over only the elements that are equal to x, then counts the result. Summing the ones for equality is one less operation.

Comment: As always from you, an insightful answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem, I'm just glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the algorithm provided by MPelletier. Since you're asking for concision, tacit phrasings may be worth looking at. Here's one such program, assigned to a name:

```
count =: +/ @: =
```

It can also be used as an anonymous verb, as in this example:

```
   4 (+/ @: =) 3 4 4 3 4 7 9
3
```

A synonym is `[: +/ =`

As MPelletier said, this algorithm works when what you want to count are atoms in a simple list. (A similar need that would require a different approach would be counting matrices matched in a list of similarly-shaped matrices.)

Comment: Yeah, once MPelletier had provided my with the algorithm, I did turn it into its tacit form. (I used the `@:` variant rather than the capped one.) I created a verb called `counts` which in its dyadic form is basically `+/ @: = "0 1` and in its monadic form returns a two-column matrix which counts the given list.

Comment: In other words, the monadic form of `counts` is `(, count&y)"0 ~. /:~ y`.

Comment: I think a monadic verb that tallies for the nub should be kept minimalistic: `[: +/"1 =` seems the "classic" calculation of this. If you want to do sorting, or joining to the nub, fine, but I recommend you don't mix those into the "main" verb.

Comment: Thanks @kaleidic, I usually go for the simplest, direct form and forget to make it tacit. My understanding of the `@`, `@.`, and `@:` adverbs is seriously lacking.

Answer (score 3):

We should probably also mention [Member of Interval](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/decapdot.htm) `E.`:

```
4 E. 3 4 4 3 4 7 9
0 1 1 0 1 0 0

+/ 4 E. 3 4 4 3 4 7 9
3
```

so

```
f =: +/ @: E.
```

eg

```
4 f 3 4 4 3 4 7 9 
3
(1 0) f (1 0 3 2 4 1 0 3)
2
```